# In Flex, can I send HTTPService POST-request instead of GET-request?

Tags: apache-flex, http, httprequest

There is known issue in `Internet Explorer (6,7)` when Flex (`HTTPService`) is loading `XML` through `SSL`. Flash Player is throwing `Error #2032: Stream Error` in that case.

As advised by [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;272359) and [others](http://faindu.wordpress.com/2008/04/18/ie7-ssl-xml-flex-error-2032-stream-error/), "Cache-Control: no-store" should be set on the server side to resolve the issue.

Unfortunately, I do not have access to application's backend, and thus I should solve it through Flex.

My goal is to load xml file with configurations at runtime.
Custom headers for `GET` requests are not allowed in Flex (let me know, if I am wrong). Thus I decided to accomplish my goal with `POST` request, and surprisingly it worked very well.

Here is the code I came with:

```
var httpService:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
httpService.url = 'config.xml';
httpService.method = 'POST';
httpService.requestTimeout = 10;
httpService.contentType = "application/xml";
httpService.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-store";
httpService.resultFormat = "e4x";
var localResponder:Responder = new Responder(
    function(event:ResultEvent):void {
        //event.result returns the required xml configuration
    },
    function(event:FaultEvent):void {
    });
var token:AsyncToken = httpService.send({});
token.addResponder(localResponder);
```

My question is: Could there be any side effects, when `POST` request is sent instead of `GET` request?

**UPDATE:**

To prove that GET-requests are stripped of headers, I've taken the code provided by @Reboog711 and created a little application. Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.rpc.http.HTTPService;
            
            protected function sendHTTPRequest(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var httpService:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
                httpService.url = 'xml.xml';
                var headerData : Object = new Object();
                headerData['Cache-Control'] = 'no-store';
                httpService.headers = headerData;
                httpService.send();
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    
    <s:Button label="SEND HTTP REQUEST" 
              horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0" click="sendHTTPRequest(event)"/>
    
</s:Application>
```

And here is what I see in Charles application, when I send that HTTP-request.

[image]

You can test it yourself right [here](http://simulator.su/test/). Moreover, while I was trying to solve my problem, I've seen many evidences that GET-requests couldn't be sent with custom headers. You may take a look [here](http://verveguy.blogspot.ru/2008/07/truth-about-flex-httpservice.html).

Thanks!

Comment: If it works and you see no errors in your browser console and no errors in your web server logs (which maybe you cannot see), I wouldn't worry about it. I wasn't aware you couldn't use a custom header w/a GET in Flex, have you tried it? Fundamentally, the difference between POST/GET is where the "message body" or data is found, and in this case you're not actually posting any data. There are some semantic differences about what a GET/POST imply (may affect caching, etc.), but I don't think there's any real harm in what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to add [headers](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/http/HTTPService.html#headers) to an HTTPService request without any problems.  I have done it before, when integrating a Flex app with the YouTube APIs.  Conceptually, it should be like this:

```
var httpService:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
var headerData : Object = new Object();
headerData['Cache-Control'] = 'no-store';
http.headers = headerData;
```

If you perform a [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Flex%20HTTPService%20HEaders&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) other links come up.  So long as your service supports both GET and POST requests; I do not know why you would experience any issues.

Comment: Thank you, @Reboog711! I've taken your code and created an application to test your statement (please see an update to the question). I would like to be proven wrong, but I am sure that custom headers work only with `POST` requests.